# php send file to sftp

Tags: php, upload, sftp

I am trying to send a file with SFTP I get error while I am trying to upload the file.
Permissions on the remote folder are ok.

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('10.0.10.245', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
echo '<br>';
ssh2_scp_send($connection,$file,"/a.xml", 0644);
print_r(error_get_last());
```

the error I got is:

```
Array 
( 
    [type] => 2 
    [message] => ssh2_scp_send(): Failure creating remote file 
    [file] => /var/www/FP1/sendFTP.php 
    [line] => 93 
 )
```

Any advise?

Comment: Can you show us the permissions of the remote folder, please? Is `$ftp_user_name` the owner of the folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start SFTP session (`ssh2_sftp`), while you use SCP later for actual transfer (`ssh2_scp_send`). You definitely do not need the `ssh2_sftp` line; and it can actually be a cause of your problem.

While technically it is possible to have both SFTP and SCP sessions over one SSH connection, I would not expect PHP to support this. Though I'm not sure.

Comment: Great! After struggling for 3 days, I came across your answer and resolved the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there are no permission problem?

`"/a.xml"` means you put the file under the root directory `/`, which won't have write permission for your ftp user usually.